# Switching between dialog box layouts without closing the dialog box

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

When my app is first run, I would like to have a welcome message displayed in a dialog box. Then the user can click next at the bottom, and the box stays but a new layout is displayed where the user can input information.

How would I go about this? It would also be great if I was able to add an animation between the two layouts, the second one sliding in from the right for example. Is this possible?

I was thinking I may be able to use

```
builder.setView(secondlayout);
```